# how to change forms as radiobutton are selected

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, radio-button

I have swing frame with 3 radio buttons and a panel below these buttons.The panel has to be different for each options of the radio-buttons.
I have to change the panel as these radiobuttons are clicked by the user.

i tried :

```
public RadioFrame() {
    initComponents();
    groupbuttons();
    changePanel();
}

private void groupbuttons(){
   //code to group these 3 buttons.
}

private void changePanel(){
  if (jradioButton1.isSelected()){
     //change the panel for radiobutton1
  }
  if (jradioButton2.isSelected()){
     //change the panel for radiobutton2
  }      if (jradioButton3.isSelected()){
     //change the panel for radiobutton3
  }
}
```

but this works only when the frame is loaded for the first time,it doesn't change as the user selects different radiobutton as the program runs.

how can i solve this ?

Comment: Isn't `JTabbedPane` the better solution?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, it is in general, but occasionally people want custom controls.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a JPanel with a CardLayout. Each page is a JPanel and a card inside the outer JPanel.

UPDATE:

To switch from one card to another, you would do:

```
CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)cardPanel.getLayout();
layout.show(cardPanel, "card name");
```

You can easily design you pages in the Netbeans visual editor.

UPDATE 2:

In your case:

```
CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)cardPanel.getLayout();
if (jradioButton1.isSelected()){
    layout.show(cardPanel, "panel1");
}
if (jradioButton2.isSelected()){
    layout.show(cardPanel, "panel2");
}
if (jradioButton3.isSelected()){
    layout.show(cardPanel, "panel3");
}
```